# Mozilla Firefox extension: Creating a new alarm

Tags: firefox, mozilla, alarm

I am working on a Mozilla Firefox extension that is creating a new alarm.

Here is the code in the `manifest.json` file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "alarms-test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts":
    [
        {
            "matches": ["https://developer.mozilla.org/*"],
            "js": ["alarms-test.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions":
    [
        "alarms"
    ]
}
```

Here is the code in the `alarms-test.js` file:

```
console.log("alarms-test: start");
const delayInMinutes = 1;
browser.alarms.create({delayInMinutes});
console.log("alarms-test: end");
```

Here are the steps that I am following:

1. In Mozilla Firefox, go to `about:debugging`
2. Click on `This Firefox` then `Load Temporary Add-on...`
3. Browse your local files to select the `manifest.json` file
4. Go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/
5. Press `F12` then click on the `Console` tab
6. See the output

Expected output:

```
alarms-test: start
alarms-test: end
```

Current output:

```
alarms-test: start
```

It means that something went wrong with the lines 2 and 3 of `alarms-test.js`.

Do you see what I forgot please?

Thank you.

Best regards.